# React keydown useeffect not working on page load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, keydown

I'm trying to listen for keydown events and this code isnt working on initial page load. If i refresh, then make some code changes, and the page refreshes, it works just fine.

Works when:

1. Open page
2. Make a code change (like adding a comment or whatever)
3. React refreshes
4. Hit the 'e' key
5. Code works as intended

Does NOT work when:

1. Open page
2. Hit the 'e' key
3. Nothing happens

I think there's an issue with my useEffect's or my keyPress function but im not sure

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { shuffle } from "../utils/shuffle";
import './player.css';

const baseUrl = (id) => `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}?autoplay=1`;
const magicKey = 'e';

function Player({ searchTerm }) {
  let [ids, setIds] = useState([]); // youtube video ids
  let [url, setUrl] = useState(baseUrl(0));
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Play next video when pressing 'e'
  const keyPress = useCallback((e) => {
    // Reset playlist when ids have all been played
    if (e.key === "e" && count >= ids.length) {
      setCount(0)
    }
    else if (e.key === magicKey) {
      setCount(cCount => cCount + 1)
    }
  },[count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
  }, [keyPress]);

  // // fetch new ids from backend based on new searchTerm
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('api call for new ids: ', searchTerm);
    // TODO sub paw patrol with either text input, or button options
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/videos?term=${searchTerm}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        setIds(shuffle(res.videoIds));
        setCount(0);
      });
  }, [searchTerm]);

  // // when the id's change, set a new url for the iframe to play
  useEffect(() => {
    setUrl(baseUrl(ids[count]));
    let videoFrame = document.getElementById('screen')
    videoFrame.src = url;
  }, [ids, count]);


  return (
      <section id="player">
        <iframe id="screen" title="youtube-player" src={url} allow='autoplay'></iframe>
      </section>
  );
}

export default Player;
```

Ive tried playying around with the useEffect params and setting the listeners in a sepereate useEffect but havent found the right combo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the array of ids as a dependency of keyPress useCallback to see if it works

Comment:  the prophet delivers !!